# marklogic - use distinct-values

Tags: marklogic

I try to get distinct values from documents. but it always return duplicate values.

```
for $uri in cts:uris((),
                     (),
                     cts:and-query(
                       cts:collection-query("/citation/company")
                 )
         )[1 to 1000]
return distinct-values( doc($uri)/PerformingOrganizations/Name)

result: 
   EARTH RESEARCH LLC
   EARTH RESEARCH LLC
   EARTH RESEARCH LLC
   EARTH RESEARCH LLC
   EARTH RESEARCH LLC
```

Why distinct-values returns duplicate values? How can I get result eliminate duplicate values.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `distinct-values` within the scope of an iterator, so it is called once for every `$uri`. First collect your sequence of values, then call `distinct-values` once for all of them.

```
let $values :=
  for $uri in cts:uris((), 'limit=1000',
    cts:and-query(cts:collection-query("/citation/company")))
  return doc($uri)/PerformingOrganizations/Name 
return distinct-values($values)
```

Also, `cts:uris` is a lexicon function that will return every result in the index unless specifically limited by an options parameter. Limiting using a predicate will result in the lexicon call returning **all** of its results first, then the sequence will be limited to the first 1000. Using options to limit instead will result in the function only ever returning the first 1000 results. For indexes with many values, not using  these options can cause performance problems.

Comment: re "Limiting using a predicate will result in the lexicon call returning all of its results first,"   This is not universally true, Sequences such as those produced by cts:uris() and most other sequences are "Lazy" -- a bounds predicate like  cts:uris()[1 to 1000]  will not necessarily fetch the entire list -- simple bounds predicates are 'passed down' in the underlying code the same as the limiting option 'limit=1000'.  However it is difficult to tell when this occurs without profiling - seemingly minor changes in  the full XQuery code can affect the compilers ability to optimize.

Comment: @DALDEI Thanks for the clarification. As you suggest, it can be a bit of a black art knowing when exactly the XQuery/XPath optimizer will do the ideal thing, so as a general rule I try to be explicit if it might matter. And to some extent the optimizer is probably a moving target, (hopefully) getting more clever in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this XQuery will helpful for you. Try this one.

```
let $uris := cts:uri-match(('*.xml'),(),cts:collection-query("/citation/company"))
let $name := for $uri in $uris
             return doc($uri)/PerformingOrganizations/Name/text()

return fn:distinct-values($name)
```